# What characters cannot be written on a passport?

Tags: passports

[Apparently](http://www.dzwww.com/xinwen/shehuixinwen/201802/t20180202_17001346.htm) the letter ü cannot be written on Chinese passports. They opt for instead writing ü as:

> yu

The name lü would get rendered as:

> lyu

Is this an international issue? What other characters (or letters) cannot be written on passports?

Comment: German passports can contain *ü,* although in the machine readable zone it is rendered with the two letters *ue.* Have a look at https://www.icao.int/publications/pages/publication.aspx?docnum=9303.  Arabic is particularly interesting.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport#Names also for a more informal discussion of the conventions.

Comment: The fun part is that the machine readable zone contains the Latin script transcription of the local version of the name, which may itself be a transcription from Latin script. Not sure if that’s always the case, but I’ve seen that on Russian visas.